# Swagger 2.0 - Inconsistent Results From Swagger Source

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Swagger source below. When I run the swagger-tools validator, I receive no errors. When I load this in the editor, I see output but it is incorrect - it shows wrong types, and an incomplete Member object. When I try to use the code generator cli java tool, I get the following errors:

> > 711 [main] ERROR io.swagger.models.properties.PropertyBuilder - no property for null, null
> >     712 [main] WARN io.swagger.util.PropertyDeserializer - no property from null, null, {ENUM=null, TITLE=null, DESCRIPTION=null, DEFAULT=null, PATTERN=null, DESCRIMINATOR=null, MIN_ITEMS=null, MAX_ITEMS=null, MIN_PROPERTIES=null, MAX_PROPERTIES=null, MIN_LENGTH=null, MAX_LENGTH=null, MINIMUM=null, MAXIMUM=null, EXCLUSIVE_MINIMUM=null, EXCLUSIVE_MAXIMUM=null, UNIQUE_ITEMS=null, EXAMPLE=null, TYPE=null, FORMAT=null}
> >     822 [main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name null
> >     822 [main] WARN io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - skipping invalid property {
> >       "type" : "array"
> >     }

```
    {
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "V1 Inmar CRM API",
    "description": "CRM API",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "produces": ["application/json"],
  "basePath": "/v1",
  "paths": {

    "/member": {
      "get": {
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "member",
        "tags": ["member"],
        "operationId": "GetMember",
        "parameters": [
          { "$ref": "#/parameters/x-inmar-rest-api-key" },
          { "$ref": "#/parameters/x-inmar-memberID" }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "success",
            "schema": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Member" }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "x-swagger-route-controller": "member",
        "tags": ["member"],
        "operationId": "PostMember",
        "parameters": [
          { "$ref": "#/parameters/x-inmar-rest-api-key" },
          { "$ref": "#/parameters/x-inmar-memberID" },
          { "$ref": "#/parameters/member" }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": { "$ref": "#/responses/generic-200" }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "parameters": {
    "x-inmar-rest-api-key": {
      "name": "X-Inmar-REST-API-Key",
      "description": "API Access Key.",
      "in": "header",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "x-inmar-memberID": {
      "name": "X-Inmar-MemberID",
      "description": "Unique ID for member.",
      "in": "header",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "member": {
      "description": "member object",
      "in": "body",
      "name": "body",
      "required": true,
      "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Member"
      }
    }
  },

  "responses": {
    "generic-200": {
      "description": "Success"
    }
  },

  "definitions": {
    "Member": {
      "description": "member",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "active": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "default": true
        },
        "identity": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "user_id"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "user_id": {
              "type": "string",
              "maxLength": 50,
              "format": "email"
            },
            "password": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 8,
              "maxLength": 20
            },
            "proxy_id": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        },
        "pii": {
          "type": "object",
          "description": "personally_identifiable_information.",
          "properties": {
            "alt_email": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "Secondary email addresses that may or may not match the id.",
              "format": "email"
            },
            "first_name": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "maxLength": 25
            },
            "last_name": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "maxLength": 25
            },
            "primary_address_one": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "maxLength": 47
            },
            "primary_address_two": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "maxLength": 47
            },
            "primary_address_city": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "maxLength": 47
            },
            "primary_address_state": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 2,
              "maxLength": 2,
              "description": "US states and US territories and Canadian provinces.",
              "enum": [
                "AA",
                "AB",
                "AE",
                "AK",
                "AL",
                "AP",
                "AR",
                "AS",
                "AZ",
                "BC",
                "CA",
                "CO",
                "CT",
                "DC",
                "DE",
                "FL",
                "FM",
                "GA",
                "GU",
                "HI",
                "IA",
                "ID",
                "IL",
                "IN",
                "KS",
                "KY",
                "LA",
                "MA",
                "MB",
                "MD",
                "ME",
                "MH",
                "MI",
                "MN",
                "MO",
                "MP",
                "MS",
                "MT",
                "NB",
                "NC",
                "ND",
                "NE",
                "NH",
                "NJ",
                "NL",
                "NM",
                "NS",
                "NT",
                "NU",
                "NV",
                "NY",
                "OH",
                "OK",
                "ON",
                "OR",
                "PA",
                "PE",
                "PR",
                "PW",
                "QC",
                "RI",
                "SC",
                "SD",
                "SK",
                "TN",
                "TX",
                "UK",
                "UT",
                "VA",
                "VI",
                "VT",
                "WA",
                "WI",
                "WV",
                "WY",
                "YT"
              ]
            },
            "primary_address_postal_code": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 5,
              "maxLength": 10
            },
            "primary_address_country": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "US",
                "CA"
              ]
            },
            "birthdate": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "language_preference": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "gender": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "male",
                "female"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "profiles": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "properties": {
              "site_id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "survey_data": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                  "survey_id",
                  "survey_responses"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "survey_id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "Unique identifier of a profile survey."
                  },
                  "survey_responses": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "required": [
                        "question_id",
                        "response_id",
                        "free_form_value"
                      ],
                      "properties": {
                        "question_id": {
                          "type": "integer",
                          "description": "Unique identifier of a profile survey question."
                        },
                        "response_id": {
                          "type": "integer",
                          "description": "Unique identifier of a profile question response.",
                          "default": 0
                        },
                        "free_form_value": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "description": "Consumer free form response",
                          "default": ""
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },

        "optins": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/OptIn"
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "OptIn": {
      "description": "survey response",
      "type": "object",
      "properties":{
        "optin_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "Unique identifier of an opt in question/choice. e.g. newsletter"
        },
        "optin_value": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [ 0, 1 ],
          "description": "Optin Response of 0=Optout and 1=Optin"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "optin_id",
        "optin_value"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run the codegen directly from the editor?